# Why QR iteration preserves the lower bandwidth?

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, computational-mathematics

[This paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/228576685_Neutrally_stable_fixed_points_of_the_QR_algorithm?enrichId=rgreq-4858cce320285134fb0b001e762f0696-XXX&enrichSource=Y292ZXJQYWdlOzIyODU3NjY4NTtBUzoxMDE5NjM0NjMxMzUyMzJAMTQwMTMyMTM5MjA2Nw%3D%3D&el=1_x_3&_esc=publicationCoverPdf) claimed that (in section 1) the [QR iteration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) preserves the lower [bandwidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_matrix) of $A$, where $A \in \mathbb{C}^{n \times n}$ is the decomposed matrix, but I cannot prove it.

I formulate the problem as follows.

> Prove: Suppose $A$ has the lower bandwidth $p$, if we perform the (shifted) QR iteration \begin{equation}
> A - \mu I = QR, \quad \bar{A} = RQ+\mu I,
> \end{equation}
> then $\bar{A}$ also has lower bandwidth $p$.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: @PegasusMitchell Sorry if this problem offended you, but why?

Comment: @PegasusMitchell what's the matter with u? Is this problem improper for this community?

Comment: @PegasusMitchell I really dont know, if this question is not acceptable, just downvote it, but why you attack me?

Comment: Interesting question.